# Chebyshev expansion of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+(x-s)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, chebyshev-polynomials

The Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind are obtained from the recurrence relation
$$\begin{aligned}T_{0}(x)&=1\\T_{1}(x)&=x\\T_{n+1}(x)&=2x\,T_{n}(x)-T_{n-1}(x)~.\end{aligned}$$
I would like to find the Chebyshev expansion (of the first kind), in $x$, of the function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+(x-s)^2}$$
where $x,s\in[-1,1]$ and $s$ is a parameter.

Comment: For the expansion you'll want to decide on a bounded interval for $x$ and which set, $T_n$ or $T^*_n$, to use. After that it's a matter of using the orthogonality relation to get the coefficients. See https://archive.siam.org/books/ot99/OT99SampleChapter.pdf

Comment: Chebyshev expansions are naturally bound to the interval $[-1,1]$. Your function isn't. So... why? I'm really sorry, but don't expect too many people here to break a sweat for some poorly motivated homework.

Comment: I'm sorry, $x,s$ are in $[-1,1]$. I edited the post.

Comment: If $s$ and $x$ are in $[-1, 1]$, why not simply approximate the function $1/(1 + 4 z^2)$ on $[-1, 1]$?